# How to pass a string value from edit text to a button in the same fragment

Tags: android, string

i have a fragment in that i made a button to collect user mobile number. In the same fragment i have made a button to toast the string value collected from edited text (mobile), I know it's a simple question but i don't know the answer please help me

this is my edit text

```
   LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_set_mobile,(ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_mobile));
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Please Input Contact Information").setIcon(
                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer).setView(
                    layout).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Dialog dialog = (Dialog) dialogInterface;
                    EditText inputMobile = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_et_mobile);
                    if (inputMobile.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                        return;
                    }
                    try{
                        long number = Long.valueOf(inputMobile.getText().toString());
                        SPManipulation.getInstance(getActivity()).setMobile(inputMobile.getText().toString());
                        mTextMobile.setText(inputMobile.getText().toString());



                        String mobile = inputMobile.getText().toString();
                        //DatabaseReference mynum = database.getReference("number");
                        DatabaseReference mynum = database.getReference().child(userID).child("number");
                        mynum.setValue(mobile);


                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Input Correct Phone Number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

This is my button code

```
  mButtonCheckout = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.checkout_pay);
    mButtonCheckout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



              FirebaseAuth   mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            String userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

            DatabaseReference mylocation = database.getReference().child(userID).child("location");
        //    mylocation.setValue(mobile); // here i need string





        }
    });
```

this is my whole code of fragment

```
package com.example.guanzhuli.foody.CartPage.fragment;



public class CheckoutFragment extends Fragment {

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

// PayPal Initialization
private static final String TAG = "iCartPayment";
//private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK;
private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;
// note that these credentials will differ between live & sandbox environments.
private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "AfNfJY2QLMIzxPpAt97YVg4GKJtMa0k8wQICuFcwIdR6bR73oexStWMQfH0nirg-WlFradZHcPnCleZg";
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
        .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
        .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
        // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
        .merchantName("Example Merchant")
        .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
        .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));


// Fragment Component Initialization
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private TextView mTextMobile, mTextTotal, mTextEditAddress, mTextEditMobil;
public static TextView mTextAddress;
private Button mButtonCheckout, mButtonCancel;





public CheckoutFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor



}

DatabaseReference databaseReference;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_checkout, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_checkout);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new CheckoutAdapter(getContext()));
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    // initial button





    mButtonCheckout = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.checkout_pay);
    mButtonCheckout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



           // Toast.makeText(getContext(),abc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            //  payOrder();






            FirebaseAuth   mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            String userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

            DatabaseReference mylocation = database.getReference().child(userID).child("location");
        //    mylocation.setValue(mobile); // here i need string











        }
    });







    mButtonCancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.checkout_cancel);
    mButtonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });
    // initial text
    mTextMobile = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkout_mobile);
    mTextMobile.setText(SPManipulation.getInstance(getActivity()).getMobile());
    mTextAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkout_address);
    mTextAddress.setText(SPManipulation.getInstance(getContext()).getAddress());



    mTextTotal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkout_total);
    mTextEditMobil = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkout_edit_mobile);
    mTextEditMobil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {





     Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Edit Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_set_mobile,(ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_mobile));
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Please Input Contact Information").setIcon(
                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer).setView(
                    layout).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Dialog dialog = (Dialog) dialogInterface;
                    EditText inputMobile = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_et_mobile);
                    if (inputMobile.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                        return;
                    }
                    try{
                        long number = Long.valueOf(inputMobile.getText().toString());
                        SPManipulation.getInstance(getActivity()).setMobile(inputMobile.getText().toString());
                        mTextMobile.setText(inputMobile.getText().toString());

                        FirebaseAuth   mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                        String userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        String mobile = inputMobile.getText().toString();
                        DatabaseReference mynum = database.getReference().child(userID).child("number");
                        mynum.setValue(mobile);


                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Input Correct Phone Number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
        }
    });
    mTextEditAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkout_edit_addr);

   mTextEditAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();


            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_set_location,(ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_location));


            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Please Input Delivery Location").setIcon(
                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer).setView(
                    layout).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Dialog dialog = (Dialog) dialogInterface;



                    EditText inputLocation = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_et_location);


                    if (inputLocation.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                        return;
                    }


                    mTextAddress.setText(inputLocation.getText().toString());
                    String bbb = inputLocation.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),bbb, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();





                }
            })
                    .setNeutralButton("Show Map", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            Intent mapAct = new Intent(getActivity(), MapsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(mapAct);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .show();

        }
    });

    mTextTotal.setText(String.valueOf(ShoppingCartItem.getInstance(getContext()).getPrice() * 1.06 + 1.99));

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            ShoppingCartItem.getInstance(getContext()).placeOrder(mTextAddress.getText().toString(), mTextMobile.getText().toString());
            ShoppingCartItem.getInstance(getContext()).clear();
            DBManipulation.getInstance(getActivity()).deleteAll();
            PaymentConfirmation confirm =
                    data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirm != null) {
                try {
                    Log.i(TAG, confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                    Log.i(TAG, confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject().toString(4));
                    /**
                     *  TODO: send 'confirm' (and possibly confirm.getPayment() to your server for verification
                     * or consent completion.
                     * See https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
                     * for more details.
                     *
                     * For sample mobile backend interactions, see
                     * https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend
                     */
                    registerOrder();
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                }
            }
            HomePageActivity.cartNumber.setText("0");
            getActivity().finish();
        } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "The user canceled.");
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
            Log.i(
                    TAG,
                    "An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getContext(), PayPalService.class));
}

private void payOrder() {
            /*
     * PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE will cause the payment to complete immediately.
     * Change PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE to
     *   - PAYMENT_INTENT_AUTHORIZE to only authorize payment and capture funds later.
     *   - PAYMENT_INTENT_ORDER to create a payment for authorization and capture
     *     later via calls from your server.
     *
     * Also, to include additional payment details and an item list, see getStuffToBuy() below.
     */
    PayPalPayment thingToBuy = getStuffToBuy(PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

    /*
     * See getStuffToBuy(..) for examples of some available payment options.
     */

    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), PaymentActivity.class);

    // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
}

private PayPalPayment getStuffToBuy(String paymentIntent) {
    //--- include an item list, payment amount details
    PayPalItem[] items = new PayPalItem[ShoppingCartItem.getInstance(getContext()).getFoodTypeSize()];
    for (int position = 0; position < ShoppingCartItem.getInstance(getContext()).getFoodTypeSize(); position++){
        int id = ShoppingCartItem.getInstance(getContext()).getFoodInCart().get(position);
        final Food curFood = ShoppingCartItem.getInstance(getContext()).getFoodById(id);
        final int curFoodNumber = ShoppingCartItem.getInstance(getContext()).getFoodNumber(curFood);
        Log.e("PRICE & NUMBER", "price: " + curFood.getPrice() + ", number: " + curFoodNumber);
        items[position] = new PayPalItem("Item No." + curFood.getId(),
                curFoodNumber,
                new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(curFood.getPrice())),"USD", curFood.getName()

        );

    }

    BigDecimal subtotal = PayPalItem.getItemTotal(items);
    BigDecimal shipping = new BigDecimal("1.99");
    BigDecimal tax = new BigDecimal("" + ShoppingCartItem.getInstance(getContext()).getPrice() * 0.06);
    PayPalPaymentDetails paymentDetails = new PayPalPaymentDetails(shipping, subtotal, tax);
    BigDecimal amount = subtotal.add(shipping).add(tax);
    PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(amount, "USD", "Foody Inc.", paymentIntent);
    payment.items(items).paymentDetails(paymentDetails);

    //--- set other optional fields like invoice_number, custom field, and soft_descriptor
    payment.custom("This is text that will be associated with the payment that the app can use.");

    return payment;
}

private void registerOrder() {
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two way

**1** : Instead on `mobile` use this

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(),inputMobile.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**2** : Create global string variable mobile like this

first create global mobile number above on `onCreateView()`

```
public String mobileNumber;
```

then in you button click in dialog init mobileNumber

```
try{
          long number = Long.valueOf(inputMobile.getText().toString());
          SPManipulation.getInstance(getActivity()).setMobile(inputMobile.getText().toString());
          mTextMobile.setText(inputMobile.getText().toString());

          FirebaseAuth   mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
          String userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
          mobileNumber = inputMobile.getText().toString();//THIS LINE CHANGED
          DatabaseReference mynum = database.getReference().child(userID).child("number");
                    mynum.setValue(mobile);


   }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Input Correct Phone Number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

Now you can use mobileNumber anywhere like in button

```
mButtonCheckout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),mobileNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you give me the 2 nd way with an example

Comment: yeah i will add

Comment: all i need is to get the value of mobile from  AlertDialog to checkout button, please help me

Comment: see my code all i need is to get the value of mobile from  AlertDialog to checkout_pay button, please help me @Radesh

Answer (score 0):

1. declare a String variable to store the value of the EditText
   `String mobileNumber = inputMobile.getText().toString();`
2. Create your Toast inside the OnClickListener.
   `Toast.makeText(getContext, mobileNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: see my code all i need is to get the value of mobile from  AlertDialog to checkout_pay button, please help me